# Google Exchange service and missing calendar events

Tags: ios, calendar, google-calendar, exchange

I have my iTouch (4th generation, up to date) syncing with Google's Exchange service, and mostly it works fine.  The problem is that some of my calendar events just seem to disappear, sometimes eventually coming back if they're events that are set to recur.

I have found no rhyme or reason to which events refuse to sync or when, but this is a problem I need to resolve somehow.

I do have several calendars syncing through the Exchange service, but I'm not missing entire calendars, just some events from various calendars, including my main (default) calendar.

Edit: My bounty expired without a solution, and I can't really place another. Please, *someone* help me. I'm desperate for a solution!

Answer (score 1):

I do need to know if you have it set to sync "All Events" in: Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars > Sync ""All Events"

Comment: Yes, it's set to sync all events under the Calendar section.

Comment: In other words, this answer doesn't help me at all.